# Find primary key of a relation

Tags: database, relational-database

I am having trouble with this question.

Find the primary key for the relation R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I) where:

```
A -> B,C
E -> F
D -> I
A,D -> G
G -> H
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it should be A,D,E

Answer (score 0):

The (only) key is `A, D, E`, in fact, if you compute the closure, you obtain:

```
1. (A,D,E)+ = A,D,E
2. You add B,C for the first dependence, so now (A,D,E)+ = A,D,E,B,C
3. You add F for the second dependence, so now (A,D,E)+ = A,D,E,B,C,F
4. You add I for the third dependence, so now (A,D,E)+ = A,D,E,B,C,F,I
5. You add G for the fourth dependence, so now (A,D,E)+ = A,D,E,B,C,F,I,G
6. And finally you add H for the last dependence, so that (A,D,E)+ = A,D,E,B,C,F,I,G,H
```

Since A,D,E determines all the attributes, it is a key. To prove that this is the only key, note that no attribute of A,D,E appears in a right side of a functional dependence, so all of them must belong to a key. And since they form a key, no other (candidate) keys can exist.

Comment: Thanks @Renzo, this is extremely helpful. Is it also safe to deduce that this is not in 3NF and is not in BCNF given G -> H ?

Comment: The relation is not in 3NF for *all* the dependencies, not only for G -> H. And in the same way, it is not in BCNF for *all* the dependencies.

Comment: That makes sense to me now. Thank you for your help. I have moved ahead and followed the steps to decompose to 3NF/BCNF and have determined the following : R1A (A,G,B,C) R1B(G,H) R2(D,I) R3(E,F) Is this correct?

Comment: Your solution is neither in 3NF, nor in BCNF. The 3NF and the BCNF arising from the respective algorithms are the following: R1(E F), R2(D I), R3 (G H), R4(A B C), R5(A D G),  R6(A D E). Note that in your solution R1A(A,G,B,C) is not correct since A->B,C, while G is determined by A,D (and so there is the need for R5. And finally, note that, since the key must be present in some relation, there is the need to include the relation R6(A D E) in the result.

Comment: And, by the way, if my solution really helped you (and *only* in this case), please don't forget to approve the answer! Thanks.